# how does Android Contacts implement its scrolling index hint?

Tags: android, scroll, contacts

android contacts has a visual effect when touching and scrolling the scrollbar, which looks like:

[image: scrolling index hint]

anyone knows how `EXACTLY the AOSP contacts APP` implements this?

I wanna know the AOSP implementation because i'm trying to change the color and text size, but cannot find where it's coded.

Answer (score 0):

this is a feature of `ListView`, called `FastScroller`. what we could customize it is writing xml attributes in the style/theme, described by Shubham's answer.

for example:

`<item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/contact_list_fastscroll_bubble</item>`